# Being in *shell* buffer, is it possible to open a file with the current Emacs application from a shell command?

Tags: shell, files

After executing the `shell` command, I have a shell buffer inside Emacs.

After executing classic `ls -l`, there is a file listed that I want to open in Emacs:

```bash
[pedro@system:~/projects/career-opportunities]$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 pedro users 58 Mar 23 12:05 README.md
```

Thus, I execute:

```bash
[pedro@system:~/projects/career-opportunities]$ emacs README.md
```

Emacs opens the README file. But, the file is open **in another** Emacs application. I would like to open this file in **the current** Emacs application.

Of course, I could use `find-file` with the classic binding of `C-x C-f` (or `counsel-find-file` in my case). Also, I could use `dired` and press return on the desired file. Anyways, I think there is a way to do what I want with shell. So, I would like to use shell better and this seems appropriate to learn.

Comment: I have no doubts that what you want is possible. The key aspect is: why would you want that? When you start `M-x shell` you're starting a bash process. If you want a tighter integration between emacs and the shell, then perhaps you should take a look at eshell.

Comment: Replace `emacs` by `emacsclient` in yr shell invocation and you are done (so long as you are running the emacs server).

Comment: Ultimately, my point is: Emacs is a shell, i.e. the outer layer between you (the computer user) and the OS. The common shell languages (bash, sh, fish, whatever) are inferior (bare-bones) shells, though useful in some situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by [Fran Burstall](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/10465/fran-burstall) (thank you!) via a comment in my question, I just need to do:

```bash
[pedro@system:~/projects/my-blog]$ emacsclient README.md 
Waiting for Emacs...
```

The chosen file opens in a new buffer. And the shell buffer indicates a new message with *Waiting for Emacs*:

```bash
[pedro@system:~/projects/my-blog]$ emacsclient README.md 
Waiting for Emacs...
```

Quite cool! I did not know about that :D